# TCP connection for authentication and UDP for data transfer ADDRESS ALREADY IN USE

Tags: java, android, sockets, tcp, udp

So basically I want to use a TCP connection as well as UDP on the same server which from my understanding should be possible. I'm using a separate address for each protocol.

I used `192.168.XX.XX` for my `TCP` connection, and `127.0.0.1` for `UDP` but on the UDP client side I always get that the **connection cannot bind** because the address is already in use, tried multiple ports combination, still no change.

I'm a junior self taught programmer; so there may be obvious errors.

**TCP THREAD/server**:

```
public class LoginWorker implements Runnable {

    private Socket client;

    public void loginWorker(Socket client) {
        this.client = client;

    }

    private ServerAccess serverAccess = new ServerAccess();

    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
            String loginData = reader.readLine();
            System.out.println(loginData);
            OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(client.getOutputStream());
            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(outputStreamWriter);
            writer.println(serverAccess.verifyGroupName(loginData));
            outputStreamWriter.flush();
            client.close();
        }

        catch (IOException e){

            System.out.println(e);
        }



    }
}
```

**UDP THREAD/server**:

```
public class LocationServer implements Runnable  {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {


    }

    @Override
    public void run() {


        try {
            InetAddress inetAddress = InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1");
            DatagramSocket datagramSocket=null;
            DatagramPacket datagramPacketReceiver=null;
            DatagramPacket datagramPacketSender=null;
            byte[] buffer1 = new byte [1024];
            byte[] buffer2 = new byte [1024];
            if (datagramSocket == null) {
                datagramSocket = new DatagramSocket();
                datagramSocket.setReuseAddress(true);
                datagramSocket.connect(inetAddress,17877);

            }

            while (true) {
                String position="Empty";
                ServerAccess serverAccess2 = new ServerAccess();
                datagramPacketReceiver = new DatagramPacket(buffer1,buffer1.length);
                datagramPacketSender = new DatagramPacket(buffer2,0,buffer2.length,inetAddress,9998);

                System.out.println("Location Server Waiting...");
                buffer1=datagramPacketReceiver.getData();
                datagramSocket.receive(datagramPacketReceiver);
                position= new String(buffer1,datagramPacketReceiver.getOffset(),datagramPacketReceiver.getLength());

                System.out.println("Location Server Received..."+position);
                String[] locationData = position.split(";");
                System.out.println("Longitude.." + locationData[1]);
                String listPos = locationData[3];
                String latitude = locationData[0];
                String longitude = locationData[1];
                serverAccess2.locationConnexion(locationData);
            }
        }

        catch (IOException e) {

            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage/server**:

```
public class Login {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {


            System.out.println("Server Initialized");
            System.out.println(InetAddress.getLocalHost());
            ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
            serverSocket= new ServerSocket(9999, 100);


            Thread udpThread = new Thread(){
                LocationServer y = new LocationServer();

                @Override
                public void run() { y.run();
                }
            };
                udpThread.start();


        LoginWorker x;
        x = new LoginWorker();

        while (true) {
            x.loginWorker(serverSocket.accept());
            x.run();
        }



    }
}
```

Comment: It's already in use. Check with a tool like `netstat` or `lsof` to see what's bound to what ports.

Comment: I looked but nothing indicates me that the port 17877 is being used on my localhost (127.0.0.1) my TCP socket do appear saying it's listening on the port 9999

Comment: You may need to set `SO_REUSEADDR` to get it to kick in properly, but I'm not sure how to do that in Java.

Comment: I already tried as you can see in my UDP thread section I used .setReuseAddress(true) I read that I need to set it before the socket binds so that's pretty much what I tried but it doesn't seem to work so far